# What is the T-SQL syntax to extract a specific word from a column of Table A based on the value of a column in Table B?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, match, lookup

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following column (called Details) in Table A:

```
Details
STD RN
CPL DEL REV
DLX RN
FAS REV
CJS SUP REV
COS RN
```

I have a column (called Category) in Table B:

```
Category
STD
CPL DEL
DLX
FAS
CJS SUP
COS
```

I need to run a query against Table A so that my output is as follows:

```
Details          Category

STD RN             STD
CPL DEL REV        CPL DEL
DLX RN             DLX
FAS REV            FAS
CJS SUP REV        CJS SUP
COS RN             COS
```

There is no link between Table A and Table B. Is there a way to write a query that will look up the words in the 'Details' of Table A and if it matches the word in the 'Category' column of Table B, then it will output the values of Table B?

Comment: The relational operator you require is semi-join ...but you have violated [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), so you will have problems with the simplest of queries..

Comment: This is a very, very bad design. Why do you think you need to combine values in the `Details` field? What are you trying to achieve? Whatever it is, there are other ways to do it, eg with many-to-many tables, or sparse columns

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is not an inherent design in the database. In fact, I am importing the data from Excel into an SQL Table and writing the logic for the extraction therein.

Comment: @user3115933 then you should split the data while importing, either in SSIS or in code. It's a lot easier to do something like this before loading the data into the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of these words is always the same (no `DEL CPL` or `CPL REV DEL`) this should be easy:

```
DECLARE @Details TABLE(Detail VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Details VALUES
 ('STD RN')
,('CPL DEL REV')
,('DLX RN')
,('FAS REV')
,('CJS SUP REV')
,('COS RN');


DECLARE @Categories TABLE(Category VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Categories VALUES
 ('STD')
,('CPL DEL')
,('DLX')
,('FAS')
,('CJS SUP')
,('COS');

SELECT d.Detail
      ,c.Category
FROM @Details AS d
INNER JOIN @Categories AS c ON d.Detail LIKE c.Category + '%'
```

This will combine all Details with (all) category(ies), that have the same beginning.

The result

```
Detail  Category
STD RN  STD
CPL DEL REV CPL DEL
DLX RN  DLX
FAS REV FAS
CJS SUP REV CJS SUP
COS RN  COS
```

But to be honest: **What you really should do is change the design!**